# How to get TYPO3 settings in the utility files?

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, extbase

```
plugin.tx_xxx {
    setting {
        storagePid = 23
    } 
}
```

I want this TYPO3 settings in utility file.
Please help me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The above method works only in controller or services  class try below it will work in any PHP files in Extension.

```
$objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
$configurationManager = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Configuration\\ConfigurationManager');
$extbaseFrameworkConfiguration = $configurationManager->getConfiguration(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FULL_TYPOSCRIPT);
$storagePid = $extbaseFrameworkConfiguration['plugin.']['tx_guesthouse_guesthouse.']['settings.']['storagePid'];
```

Comment: Or use `ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FRAMEWORK` for  only the configuration of the current plugin.

Answer (score 7):

> Only for TYPO3 Backend

For multi domain set root before obtaining configuration

```
$configurationManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Configuration\\BackendConfigurationManager');
$configurationManager->currentPageId = ROOT_PID_OF_YOUR_DOMAIN;
$extbaseFrameworkConfiguration = $configurationManager->getTypoScriptSetup();

//Following will be resultant array, find your required stuff from it
print_r($extbaseFrameworkConfiguration);
```

> **Note**: Don't forget to extend your class with `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\BackendConfigurationManager` in
>   order to obtain access for it's protected variables

Comment: Your hint about the rootpage just saved me a lot of time. Thx

Comment: FYI: Currently `currentPageId` is `protected` and has no public setter for this.

Answer (score 6):

You can add below line in the your controller.

```
$objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');    
$configurationManager = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Configuration\\ConfigurationManager');
$setting = $configurationManager->getConfiguration(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_SETTINGS);   
$ts_config = $setting['plugin.']['tx_xxxx.']['settings.']['storagePid'];
```

I think it will helpful to you. You can also used this typo3 settings in the services files as well.

Comment: I think this is overly complicated. In an extbase context, you can let the framework inject you a ConfigurationManager directly. Then you can use `$settings = $configurationManager->getConfiguration(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_SETTINGS);`, you don't need the full TS.

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43519092/2444812

Comment: Within controller this is not a case at all you don't even need to do it yourself, as controller those it itself and returns in its `$settings` property. The question is about Utlity classes, or Scheduler tasks, etc, there it is much more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Now,In Typo3 8.X, currentPageId is protected so, we could not set it directly, and there would not be any set method defined in core class. Following is correct code as per new version that may help you. Thanks for the correct direction.

```
$configurationManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Configuration\\BackendConfigurationManager');
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($configurationManager);
$configurationManager->getDefaultBackendStoragePid(); 
$extbaseFrameworkConfiguration = $configurationManager->getTypoScriptSetup();

//Following will be resultant array, find your required stuff from it
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($extbaseFrameworkConfiguration);
```

Answer (score 1):

In any TYPO3 version including 10, one may use this one-liner:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['plugin.']['tx_xxxx.']['settings.']['storagePid'];
```

To get rid of the dots, use `TypoScriptService`, thus

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\TypoScript\TypoScriptService;

$typoScriptService = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(TypoScriptService::class);
$typoScriptSettings = $typoScriptService->convertTypoScriptArrayToPlainArray($GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup);
    
$storagePid = $typoScriptSettings['plugin']['tx_xxxx']['settings']['storagePid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also only load the *CONFIGURATION_TYPE_SETTINGS*:

```
  $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\Extbase\\Object\\ 
ObjectManager');
  $configurationManager = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Configuration\\ConfigurationManager');
  $pluginSettings = $configurationManager->getConfiguration(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_SETTINGS, null, 'tx_guesthouse_guesthouse');
  $storagePid = $pluginSettings['storagePid'];
```

IMHO this is more effective because it does not load the whole TS tree.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late to the party, but there is also [99° Helpers for TYPO3](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/nnhelpers) extension, which contains methods for fetching TS. i.e.

[`\nn\t3::Settings()->getFullTyposcript($pid = NULL);`](https://docs.typo3.org/p/nng/nnhelpers/main/en-us/Helpers/Classes/settings.html#nn-t3-settings-getfulltyposcript-pid-null)

###### Sample one-liners would look like (note: without trailing dots!):

```php
$mySettings = \nn\t3::Settings()->getFullTyposcript()
                      ['plugin']['tx_myext_myplugin']['settings'];
```

or even, single value:

```php
$storagePid = \nn\t3::Settings()->getFullTyposcript()
                      ['plugin']['tx_myext_myplugin']['settings']['storagePid'];
```

###### de facto

this method is just a wrapper for `ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FULL_TYPOSCRIPT` approach suggested in other answer, and you don't need to install a whole large toolbox for one, simple thing, but if someone already uses 99° Helpers (really nice thing IMHO) can use it within seconds. Bonus tip: mentioned method uses internal caching to make things even faster.