# Access Repository from Resource folder

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have a Typo3 Extension (Typo3 CMS 6.2) and I want to access the repository `globalSettingsRepository` from a PHP file which is located in /Resource/PHP/.

The dependency injection does not work although I cleared the cache:

```
/**
 * globalSettingsRepository
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\Institutsvideoverwaltung\Domain\Repository\GlobalSettingsRepository
 * @inject
 */
public $globalSettingsRepository = NULL;
```

The namespace of the PHP is the same as my controllers.

I have also tried this in order to create an instance of the globalSettingsRepository:

```
$objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
```

Which does not work either because /TYPO3/CMS/... was not found.

Does anyone have a solution? Is there even a way to access a repository from /Resources?

Thanks alot.

Comment: i am not getting you exactly but i think your are looking for this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839907/how-to-get-typo3-settings-in-the-utility-files/30839969#30839969

Comment: @Vishal Thanks for your answer but actually I am trying the option with \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('Tx_Extbase_Object_ObjectManager');    which does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that should be fixed in your extension.

First of all, you should not use `TYPO3` as vendor for your extension. This is only for the core and official extensions.

Second, you must stick to conventions.

```
\TYPO3\Institutsvideoverwaltung\Domain\Repository\GlobalSettingsRepository
```

This means that you must have a class called `\TYPO3\Institutsvideoverwaltung\Domain\Repository\GlobalSettingsRepository` at the following path: `/typo3conf/ext/institutsvideoverwaltung/Classes/Domain/Repository/GlobalSettingsRepository.php`.

It seems that you don't and instead put it in `Resources/PHP`.

If you want to use a class from `Resources/PHP`, you need to either include it manually using `require_once()` or you need to make sure that your class is autoloaded properly. The requirements for autoloading changed from version 6 to 7, so you need to state which version you're using. Nevertheless it doesn't make sense to break convention and then have a lot of effort of there is a simple way.

Comment: The GlobalSettingsRepository is located at the path you just posted. One file is located in the folder Repository (the GlobalSettingsRepo.php) and the other one (also a PHP file) is at Resources/Private/PHP/. And I think my problem is to build a connection between these two locations.
The version is as is posted Typo3 CMS 6.2 with Extbase 6.2.